# C# WPF horizontal scrollbar for ScrollViewer RepeatButtons only on either side of contents

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollview

Is there a way to get a scroll viewer with the RepeatButtons only and to force the buttons to the edge of the contents?

I want it to look like this:

```
  +---+-------------------------------------------------------------+---+
  |   |                                                             |   |
  | < | Contents here...............................................| > |
  |   |                                                             |   |
  +---+-------------------------------------------------------------+---+
```

Where the middle is the content of the ScrollViewer, and the left and right are RepeatButtons which will scroll the contents.

I was thinking I could either use a custom ScrollBar (but I don't know much about this or how to make the buttons go outside the content), or I could just use RepeatButtons and connect their click to the ScrollViewer. Which way (if either) would be better/easier?

Comment: have you find any solution for this ? I am also looking to do a similar thing . Want to list 100s of image thumbnails inside a scrollviewer and alllow user to click prev & next

Comment: This is from 2 years ago while I was working at an internship, I honestly have no idea anymore what I did. I'm guessing I followed the advice of the selected answer below, so that's probably a good bet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no reason you cannot use a [ScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.aspx). Configure the event handlers of your two arrows (left/right) to minipulate [ScrollToHorizontalOffset()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltohorizontaloffset.aspx) and [ScrollToVerticalOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltoverticaloffset.aspx).